# Open folder by using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to open a specific folder by using intent, now its working only when es file manager is available ,i want to open the folder even es file manager is not there, it should work with the inbuilt file manager, what the changes i have to make with my code, any help will be appreciated

here is my code

```
   Button button=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AudioRecords/");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");

            if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getActivity().getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
            {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file
                // explorer app installed on your device
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open folder by using intent, i want to open the folder even  file manager is not there

You can't do it in Android API version below 19 (KITKAT) without installed file manager.

```
  public void openFolder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/myFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Comment: So i should write your code in the else part of my code ? @darish

Comment: what i am planing to do is if ES file manager is there then my code should execute else your code should execute, how can i do ?

Comment: @Jaison_Joseph what is the problem? just paste my code in the else part

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old thread but this opens a folder in file explorer .. if i click n some file to open it, it returns back to activity instead of opening application. Any idea about that @Darish I am new to intents too